# Set vb6 form to instance of a hardcoded form

Tags: vb6

I have a 2 Forms. Form1 opens Form2. Form2 after clicking a value, sends that value to a textbox located in Form1. It is hardcoded so that inside Form2 it explicitly states `Form1.txtbox.Text = "Whatever i clicked"` Form2 then closes and I am now sitting at Form1, however the txtbox.text has not received the new value from Form2.

In the immediate window `Form1.txtbox.text = "Whatever I clicked"` is alright, however `txtbox.text = ""` within the context of Form1 is blank.

I opened Form1 using `Forms.Add("Form1")` now is there anyway to set this instance of the form into the hardcoded instance? I imagine the error is occurring because `Forms.Add("Form1")` creates an instance of that form while `Form1.show` is the actual form. Is there anyway to match these two up to be the same object?

Comment: I would suggest Form1 opens Form2 modally -> Form2 hides itself when you click close, then Form1 gets the value from Form2. Finally Form1 unloads Form2.

Comment: Yeah Form1 does in fact open in modally, but i think its because of how i am opening form1 in the first place. `Set ftemp = Forms.Add("Form1) ftemp.show` compared to `Form1.Show` in the latter i can explicitly make calls to the objects inside the form and it will change, however the former does not allow me to do it.

Comment: When you create Form1 you create two things: a class called Form1 that you can create instances of and a predeclared global instance named Form1.  You could do something like `Set Form1 = New Form1` but that gets a little silly, or perhaps the clunkier `Set Form1 = Forms.Add("Form1")` which is about the same thing.

Comment: Yeah i was trying to open a form with only knowing the name of the form, because using Set Form1 you would have to know what the form name is, causing a huge if/select statement based on how many forms you have. If i sent a `FormName` to a sub i would have to `If FormName = "Form1" then Set Form1 = Forms.Add("Form1") elseif FormName = "Form2" then Set Form2 = Forms.Add("Form2") etc.` which is ideally what i am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for this is using what Bob77 said and applying it to the form.

When loading Form1 using the `Forms.Add("Form1")` method if you were to implement `Set Form1 = Me` in Form_Load it will now set the reference of Me to be Form1 so that when you made direct changes to it in Form2 using `Form1.Foo = "bar"` then it would work.